# How to get Instagram Audience insights for any user?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am building a website that shows their follower/audience insights to me.

I want to get follower-engagement, audience countries, age group etc for any user who authorized this data to my web-app

I am not finding anything for Instagram, I have found multiple resources for Facebook but not Instagram.

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API is not publicly available for the use case outlined in your question.

The available API is intended for Instagram Businesses and Creators who need insight into, and full control over, all of their social media interactions.

[This is](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) as far as you can go with it.

Comment: can the creator or business themselves share the insights available to them with third-parties?